# Instantiate OpenModelica model inside package from command line (omc)

Tags: openmodelica

I am trying to create the flat modelica code of a model, which is inside a package from the command line using open modelica (omc).

If I have a `.mo`-file which contains just one model I can easily create the instantiation by

```
omc myModel.mo > myModel.mof
```

The question is if I have this file:

```
package TestPackage

  model TestModel2
    Real y;
  end TestModel2;

  model TestModel
    Real x(start=1);
    TestModel2 a;
    equation
      x=a.y;
      der(x)=a.y;
  end TestModel;

end TestPackage;
```

how do i create the flat code for `TestModel`?

(Using OMEdit I get the correct code by instantiating `TestModel`:

```
class TestPackage.TestModel
  Real x(start = 1.0);
  Real a.y;
equation
  x = a.y;
  der(x) = a.y;
end TestPackage.TestModel;
```

)

Comment: Should work wih: omc -i=TestPackage.TestModel (depending on version it would be +i instead of -i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically as I said in the comment +i=Path.To.Model:

```
adrpo@dev MINGW64 ~/dev/OpenModelica/build/bin
$ ./omc +i=TestPackage.TestModel myModel.mo
class TestPackage.TestModel
  Real x(start = 1.0);
  Real a.y;
equation
  x = a.y;
  der(x) = a.y;
end TestPackage.TestModel;
```

Comment: thank you, for me `omc -i=TestPackage.TestModel TestPackage.mo > TestModel.mof` did what I wanted.. (+i and -i both worked)